# Running multiple python scripts, one asking for input, does not allow input script to run. Also, how do I run simultaneous scripts(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, simultaneous

I have two python scripts, one that needs to continuously get input from the user and write into a file while the other simultaneously continuously check for updates from the file. My problem is that when running the check script, the os system terminal "position" seems to be already filled and I can not run the input script. It either shows the check scripts terminal or stays on a blinking cursor on the cmd terminal and not loading up. Also, I am unable to find a way to make both of the scripts run indefinitely until the user kills the process. Also, it might be my pc, but when running

```
while True:
    check()
```

in my check script, it freezes my pc and also does not allow the input script to run
BTW, my pc had been having some problems, so I am going to reset it today and I hope that is the problem, but I have been going crazy over this problem and don't trust my judgement on this anymore:(

#my check script

```
def check():
    with open('Tasks.txt','r') as file:
        data = file.readlines()
    if not "Neuron" in data and len(data)!=0:
        i=0
        Chars = data[0].split(" ")
        while(i<len(Chars)):
            c=0
            print(len(data[0]))
            print('Count:' + str(i))
            print('Chars are ' + Chars[i])
            while(c<len(Chars[i])):
                Neuron.createNeuron(Chars[i][c-1:c])
                c+=1
            i+=1
        data.pop(0)
        Neuron.writeData('Tasks.txt',data,'w')
        #os.system('py Create.py')
check()
```

#my user input script

```
def CM():

    String = input(">")
    #res = ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in String)
    #print(res)
    
    Neuron.writeData('Logs.txt',Neuron.writeData('Tasks.txt',(' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in String)+'\n'),'a'),'a')
    CM()
CM()
```

Comment: You need to run them in different terminal windows.

Comment: This isn't really a Python question, it's a shell question. If you're using a *nix shell you can run background processes by putting an ampersand (&) at the end of the command. I'm sure Windows has something similar if you're using Windows. You need to run the first process as a background process before trying to run the second process

Comment: Why need multiple scripts when you have multithreading :)

Comment: Barmar I don't know how to do that.
Michael, I  actually haven't really thought about that. I will try that.
@HjSin, I have tried multithreading and I believe that works, but they seem to keep running while not doing anything. Also I wrote them to print back what they do and I can not see that when I use multithreading. I created a log file, but I have to open it every time to see the updated file. Also, Stack Overflow doesnt let me @ multiple people:(

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the answer. Originally both files actually could run, but one of them, the input file, had to be opened from the IDLE and then run there. To run them both simultaneously repetitively was to put
`os.system('py Create.py')`
at the end of the file. So it would run a new session of the py script.

Also, I imported a file that was not just functions but commands also and it ran them, which is why I was unable to use the Input script.